# XAMPP MySQL stop running query

Tags: mysql, xampp

in a past few days I have a problem with my XAMPP (v3.2.2). The problem is that MySQL randomly stops running a query in PHP. Then I need to restart MySQL from XAMPP console and it is working again. There is no error in XAMPP console. I can see the page (i guess that Apache is working) but when I run for example some search query in PHP I won't show result until I restart MySQL in XAMPP.

I am a beginner at using XAMPP so please can you suggest how to find what is causing the problem.

Comment: Start with MySQL error logs, if you need to restart MySQL to get things working again.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to read mysql error log, i have file 'mysql_error.log in XAMPP\mysql\data but when i try to open it say that file is to large to be open (almost 2GB)

Comment: Then you need to find a reader that can read such large text files. But a 2GB error file indicates that something is really wrong with MySQL.

Comment: I managed to open error file, and i see this error repeated mostly.
`[ERROR] InnoDB: Table phpmyadmin/pma_usergroups in the InnoDB data dictionary has tablespace id 7, but tablespace with that id or name does not exist. Have you deleted or moved .ibd files? This may also be a table created with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE whose .ibd and .frm files MySQL automatically removed, but the table still exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary`
This show for many tables

Comment: Then you have a MySQL admin issue, not a programming one. This question is better suited for the DBA stackexchange site instead of SO.

Comment: Thank you, i will ask question there

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your box ran out of free ram, and the kernel killed it to protect the system stability. Try an instance with more ram!
You need to tune the memory usage of the running processes and limit the number of concurrent connecions to apache and mysql - or get more memory.